# Call a function on an element added to DOM after initial page load

Tags: jquery

I have a page which in the footer I include `jQuery.js` and `anotherJsFunctionThing.js`

Also in the footer to fire the latter I bind it to an element:

```
function doIt(){
  $('.newElement').anotherJsFunctionThing({...})
}
```

How can I fire this if the element `.newElement` is added into the DOM after the page is loaded?

Currently when I call `doIt()` it fails, because, when `jQuery.js` and `anotherJsFuntionThing.js` were loaded, `.newElement` did not exist

This is what I tried but it failed...

```
function doIt(){
  $('.newElement').on('create', function(){
    $('.newElement').anotherJsFuntionThing({...})
  });
  $('.newElement').trigger('create');
}
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: Why don't you convert creation of .newElement to a function, and do the binding within that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your current tree won't contain the new element yet, you'll start at the top.

```
$(document).find(".newElement").anotherThing()
```

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin worked for me to watch for initialized DOM events.  https://github.com/AdamPietrasiak/jquery.initialize

Your code would look something like this:

```
$(".newElement").initialize(function(){
    $(this).anotherJsFunctionThing({...})
});
```